# Orthogonal eigenvectors of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Whether there is a variable $\alpha$ such that the eigenvectors of the matrix $A$ are orthogonal?

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3&1&1\\0&2&1\\0&\alpha&4\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Ok, so I've started with calculating the eigenvalues of the matrix, but these values depend on variable $\alpha$ and I don't know what to do further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the expressions for the eigenvectors in terms of alpha (I've replaced all alpha's with a's for less typing):

$$v_1 = (1,0,0),$$ 
$$v_2 = \left(\frac{1-a+\sqrt{1+a}}{a\sqrt{1+a}}, \frac{-1-\sqrt{1+a}}{a}, 1\right),$$
$$
v_3 = \left(\frac{-1+a+\sqrt{1+a}}{a\sqrt{1+a}},\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+a}}{a},1\right).
$$

Now, using the orthogonality conditions for the pairs of vectors, you should find three equations in terms of $a$ from the inner product expressions, and if any of them conflict, then there exists no such $a$. If there is one such $a$, then it is possible.

Comment: You mean equations that the Gram-Schmidt process implies?

Comment: No, the equations that result from the mutual orthogonality of the vectors: $0 = v_1 \cdot v_2$, $0 = v_1 \cdot v_3$, and $0 = v_2 \cdot v_3$.

Comment: Right, much easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT.** I assumed (without reason) that the OP was looking for a basis of $\mathbb R ^3$ of eigenvectors. I think that the answer can be interesting itself, so I leave it here. If it's off-topic, feel free to delete this (@moderators).

There's no need to calculate the eigenvectors, since it can be shown directly that such a basis does not exist.

In fact, let $T:V\to V$ be an endomorfism of a metric vector space, endowed with a scalar product $s(\cdot,\cdot) $, and suppose that $T$ admits an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors, $\{e_i\}$, with eigenvalues $\{\lambda _i\}$.
Let's calculate $s(T(v),w)$ for $v,w\in V$.

$$s(T(v),w)=s(\sum v_i T(e_i), \sum w_j e_j)=s(\sum \lambda _iv_i e_i, \sum w_j e_j)\\=\sum _{i,j}\lambda _iv_iw_j \delta_{ij}=^{\text {why?}}\sum _{i,j}\lambda _j v_i w_j \delta _{ij}=...=s(v,T(w)).$$

So the endomorfism is symmetric.

Now, if $V=\mathbb R ^n$ with the canonical scalar product $s(x,y)=y^T x$, and $T=A\cdot$, for $A\in \text M _{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$, then what we have proved is that if $A$ has $n$ orthogonal eigenvectors, then $s(Ax,y)=s(x,Ay)$. But $$y^TAx=s(Ax,y)=s(x,Ay)=(Ay)^T x=y^T A^T x,$$
and this implies $A=A^T$.

Moral: an endomorfism which has a basis of orthogonal eigenvectors is symmetric. In the case of $\mathbb R ^n$, where the endomorfism is given by a matrix, the matrix itself is symmetric.

The converse of what I've proved is also true (and much more useful): see the [Spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Comment: This shows that $A$ does not have a set of orthogonal eigenvectors which spans $\mathbb{R}^3$.  It does not rule out the possibility that $A$ has a set of fewer than 3 orthogonal eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eigenvalues%5B%28%20%7B%20%7B3,%201,%201%7D,%20%7B0,%202,%201%7D,%20%7B0,%20%5C%5BAlpha%5D,%204%7D%20%7D%20%29%5D) gives the eigenvalues of the matrix as $\lambda_1 = 3, \lambda_2 = 3 + \sqrt{\alpha+1}, \lambda_3 = 3 - \sqrt{\alpha + 1}$.  Thus, for $\alpha = -1$, the matrix will have only a single eigenvalue $\lambda = 3$.  Thus, all the eigenvectors lie in the same eigenspace.

Can you show that there is an orthogonal set of vectors which spans this eigenspace?